# Why I'm getting a blank page from running a node server that point to the /dist folder of an Angular app?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

My simple node server is:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/page/index.html');
})

app.listen(3335, () => { console.log('Server is listening on 3335'); });
```

But I'm getting the index file that seems not running the main.js
The Angular app, at the moment it's literally a page/component that is app.component.ts, so there is not any routing.

[image]

Comment: can you share your angular.json code?

Comment: Are you using angular router in this project?

Comment: Also please check network tab if every script is loaded properly

Comment: @PatrykBrejdak as I said in the post, I'm not using any routing.
Indeed my problem is that I'm not loading static files, properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use **express.static()** for serving static files.

It is because you have set a response of 'index.html' file for each and every request the server would receive. The first response would be good that's the index.html page only as expected. But, the index.html page must be having some *script* and *css* tags to fetch your Angular Javascript code which I assume would be on the same node server. So when the browser would encounter a line like:

```
<script src="/angularApp.js"></script>
```

..in your index.html file while parsing it, it would make another request to the node server for `http://localhost:<port>/angularApp.js` but would get the index.html file as the response as that is what you have set.

Do it like this to serve static files like .html, .css, .js or what have you:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
```

Comment: What you're saying makes sense, so what shall I do to make the Angular app working? I changed into `app.get('/index')`, but I'm still getting the same blank page.

Comment: app.get('/index') is completely wrong. I think you need to brush up your knowledge of express and routing first to use it properly. Anyways, I have updated my answer. Please check for the same.

Comment: I changed into `app.get('/')`

Comment: That is incorrect. The explanation for why it is incorrect is a bit more involved. Please read more about express and express routing. And see my updated answer.

Comment: Ok got it, my application is building into **/dist/page**, now it's working, thank you very much

Comment: What's it incorrect o.O, for each request on `app.get('/')` I'm serving the index.html file. Maybe you referring the fact I wrote `app.get('/', withoutCallbackHere)` ?